# Exportacion datos con ExtJS en fichero Excel

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, extjs

Estoy intentando exportar uno o muchos registros de un panel a una plantilla de Excel. A dia de hoy sólo puedo exportar un registro seleccionado pero quiero mejorar esta parte. He probado varias posibilidades pero o me imprime solo un registro o me imprime todo el panel,no las que selecciono yo. Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

El codigo ExtJS es:

```
var prevFnExcel = function(grid, store, selModel){
        var parameters = store.data.keys.toString();
        var url = ctx + '/facturas.do?op=exportarExcel&idsFacturas=' + parameters;

        Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
            tag: 'iframe',
            id:'informeIframe',
            frameBorder: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            css: 'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;',                       
            src: url
      });
     return false;
};
```

Como estoy trabajando con Spring y uso el mvc, la clase implementada Java es:

```
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see pack.senectus.facturas.service.FacturasService#exportarExcel(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.io.InputStream, java.lang.Integer)
     */
    @Override
    public void exportarExcel(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream reporte, List<Integer> idsFacturas) throws ClassNotFoundException, Exception{

        List<DatosFactura> listaDatosFactura = new ArrayList<DatosFactura>();

        for (Integer id : idsFacturas) {
            DatosFactura datosFactura = new DatosFactura();
            Sene1FacturaTeleasistencia factura = (Sene1FacturaTeleasistencia) sene1FacturaTeleasistenciaDAO.getById(id);
            datosFactura.setSene1FacturaTeleasistencia(factura);
            listaDatosFactura.add(datosFactura);
        }

        String titulo = "export_facturas.xls";
        JasperUtils.generarExcelJasperReport(reporte, listaDatosFactura, null, response, titulo);

    }
```

Y el controlador Java es:

```
public ModelAndView exportarExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException, Exception{
        String dev = "";
        String ids = ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "idsFacturas", "");
        String[] idsFacturas = ids.split(",");
        try{
            InputStream reporte = request.getSession(true).getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/reportes/facturaExcel.jrxml");
            facturaTeleasistenciaService.exportarExcel(response, reporte, Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(Stream.of(idsFacturas).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())));
        } catch (BusinessException e) {

            dev = Utils.successJsonWithId(Boolean.FALSE, e.getMessage(), 1);
        }
        return createJSONMaV(dev);
}
```

Comment: y si devuelves un zip con los excels dentro?

Comment: Hola,solo tengo que generar un excel donde haya de 1 a n registros. Esos registros se vinculan a un id y tienen un checkbox para seleccionarlos.A dia de hoy solo me imprime todos los que salen en el panel..Solo necesito que se impriman con que selecciono con el checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Para conocimiento general después de estar pensando en ello os dejo la solución por si os sirve algún dia.

```
var prevFnPDF = function(grid, store, selModel){
        var recordSelected = selModel.selections.map;
        var obj = new Array();
        for (r in recordSelected) {
            obj.push(r);
        }
        var url = ctx + '/facturas.do?op=exportarPdf&idsFacturas=' + obj.toString();
```